# change datalist input when another changes

Tags: python, html, django

I have two datalist input like this.

```
<input list="Province" name="Province" id="1">
<datalist id="Province">
       {% for item in province_list %}
           <option >{{item.Name}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
</datalist>

<input list="City" name="City" id="2">
<datalist id="City">
       {% for item in city_list %}
           <option >{{item.Name}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
</datalist>
```

i want when user select Province, i show list of that province city in input2.

Answer (score 0):

I use JavaScript as below:

```
    $("input[name=Province]").on('input', function () {
        province = $(this).val();
        dataList.empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get_cars_"+province,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                    $("input[name=City]").append("<option value='" + 
                     data[i].city + "'></option>");

                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, err) {
                console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
            }
        });
 });
```

In server side handle "/get_cities_\w+" request.
Remove second "for" statement in html code:

```
<datalist id="City">
</datalist>
```

Server side code in Django:

```
def getTheVendorProducts(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
    try:
        uriQueri = request.build_absolute_uri()
        province = uriQueri.split('_')[]
        province = urllib.parse.unquote(province.split('?')[0])
        vendorProduct= getTheCitiesOfprovince(province)
        return HttpResponse(convertListToJson(vendorProduct), 'application/json')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return failedHttpResponse()
```

You need to define your own "getTheCitiesOfprovince" and "convertListToJson" functions. Visit [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/aaecb7bc-18d2-44c5-8d81-07b8cb634a0b.aspx) For more information about this type questions.